# the output got rounded after for loop

Tags: java

I write the following code with a for loop.

```
double d1 = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    d1 += 0.1;
 }

System.out.println(d1);
```

The output is 0.7999999999999999. It is supposed to be 0.8. but I don't understand what causes it and how to avoid the rounding problem in the future.

Comment: *how to avoid the rounding problem in the future* use a type with arbitrary precision like [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: or accept that it exists and format your output to show an acceptable appearing result: `System.out.printf("%.4f%n", d1);`